# Widevine DRM not supported on this device: AWS SNS Mobile Push notification

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, amazon-sns

Getting "***Widevine DRM not supported on this device***" exception when pushing a notification from AWS SNS to Android Emulator.

Steps followed

1. Developed Android mobile app and running in Android Emulator API 19
2. Registered my APP in Firebase of Google Cloud and can send notification to my mobile app from Firebase console.
3. Registered in AWS Cloud and SNS Service.
4. Downloaded java code from [SNS Sample Application](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/samples/snsmobilepush.zip) and provided all details required form GCM + Android
5. Used SNSMobilePush.java class to push sample notifications (SampleMessageGenerator.getSampleAndroidMessage()) to my running mobile emulator app
6. No notification found in Android.
7. Checked Android logs and found "***Widevine DRM not supported on this device
                                                                     android.media.UnsupportedSchemeException: Failed to instantiate drm object.***"
   exception.

Any idea about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notification doesn't work for emulators. We have to run the app on actual device to test notifications.